# have number of modified and unknown mercurial files on prompt

Tags: regex, mercurial, sed, prompt

I'm using the [hg prompt](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/hg-prompt/) extension to have a nice prompt while working with hg.

Right now my prompt looks like this:

```
~/my/current/path [hg default !]
```

the `'!'` part in the prompt I get via the `{status}` keyword of the `hg prompt` showing me that are modified files. It shows a `'?'` for unknown files

But I want something similar to `posh-hg` where it also shows the number of modified or unknown files.

I know I can get this information with `hg summary` but my `sed` fu is failing me on getting the regex correct to get the totals.

an example of the output of the `hg summary` command:

```
parent: 0:16ed527e220f tip
 parent commit message
branch: default
commit: 5 modified, 2 unknown
update: (current)
```

doing a hg summary | grep 'commit' I get back the correct line:

```
$ hg summary | grep 'commit'
commit: 5 modified, 2 unknown
```

given the output above, how can I get the number of modified and unknown files so that I can make my prompt look like this:

`[hg default 5! 2?]`

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
hg sum | sed -ne '/^commit:/{s/^commit: //;s/ modified/\!/;s/ unknown/?/;s/,//g;p}'
```

... although there might be a more elegant way to do it.

You can probably figure out the `added`, `deleted` etc part by yourself.